# Construction of two dimensional numpy array from unequally shaped one dimensional arrays | Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

In python have three one dimensional arrays of different shapes (like the ones given below)

```
a0 = np.array([5,6,7,8,9])
a1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
a2 = np.array([11,12])
```

I am assuming that the array `a0` corresponds to an index `i=0`, `a1` corresponds to index `i=1` and `a2` corresponds to `i=2`. With these assumptions I want to construct a new two dimensional array where the rows would correspond to indices of the arrays (`i=0,1,2`) and the columns would be entries of the arrays `a0, a1, a2`.

In the example that I have given here, I will like the two dimensional array to look like

```
result = np.array([ [0,5], [0,6], [0,7], [0,8], [0,9], [1,1], [1,2],\
           [1,3], [1,4], [2,11], [2,12]  ])
```

I will very appreciate to have an answer as to how I can achieve this. In the actual problem that I am working with, I am dealing more than three one dimensional arrays. So, it will be very nice if the answer gives consideration to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy` stack functions to speed up:

```
aa = [a0, a1, a2]
np.hstack(tuple(np.vstack((np.full(ai.shape, i), ai)) for i, ai in enumerate(aa))).T
```

Comment: @liliscent: Thanks for the answer. It is very helpful. I am dealing with thousands of arrays. So, I am also trying to see if I can find ways to avoid manually listing all arrays in `aa`. But still, thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be a simple list comprehension:

```
result = np.array([[i, arr_v] for i, arr in enumerate([a0, a1, a2]) 
                             for arr_v in arr])

>>> result
array([[ 0,  5],
       [ 0,  6],
       [ 0,  7],
       [ 0,  8],
       [ 0,  9],
       [ 1,  1],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 1,  3],
       [ 1,  4],
       [ 2, 11],
       [ 2, 12]])
```

Adressing your concern about scaling this to more arrays, you can easily add as many arrays as you wish by simply creating a list of your array names, and using that list as the argument to `enumerate`:

```
.... for i, arr in enumerate(my_list_of_arrays) ...
```

Comment: Many thanks. This answer is very helpful. Since I have thousands of one dimensional arrays, I am trying to see if I can avoid having to manually create my_list_of_arrays. But, still, many thanks for the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an almost vectorized approach -

```
L = [a0,a1,a2] # list of all arrays
lens = [len(i) for i in L] # only looping part*
out = np.dstack(( np.repeat(np.arange(len(L)), lens), np.concatenate(L)))
```

*The looping part is simply to get the lengths of the arrays, which should have negligible impact on the total runtime.

Sample run -

```
In [19]: L = [a0,a1,a2] # list of all arrays

In [20]: lens = [len(i) for i in L]

In [21]: np.dstack(( np.repeat(np.arange(len(L)), lens), np.concatenate(L)))
Out[21]: 
array([[[ 0,  5],
        [ 0,  6],
        [ 0,  7],
        [ 0,  8],
        [ 0,  9],
        [ 1,  1],
        [ 1,  2],
        [ 1,  3],
        [ 1,  4],
        [ 2, 11],
        [ 2, 12]]])
```

Another way could be to avoid `np.repeat` and use some array-initialization + cumsum method, which would be better for large number of arrays, as shown below -

```
col1 = np.concatenate(L)
col0 = np.zeros(len(col1), dtype=col1.dtype)
col0[np.cumsum(lens[:-1])] = 1
out = np.dstack((col0.cumsum(), col1))
```

Or use `np.maximum.accumulate` to replace the second `cumsum` -

```
col0[np.cumsum(lens[:-1])] = np.arange(1,len(L))
out = np.dstack((np.maximum.accumulate(col0), col1))
```

Comment: Many thanks for the post. It is super fast and very useful. =)